# Compare dates in batch (for update)

Tags: batch-file, updates

I'm programming a program's launcher and I wanted to self-update (but when I put wget.exe, it didn't exist). So I changed to a comparing dates "Update", but it doesn't work:

`set UpdateDate=11/11/2015`

`if %date% GEQ %UpdateDate% goto NOTUPDATED`

`if %date% LSS %UpdateDate% goto UPDATED`

Then, I tested and everything went OK. But I also wanted to try *NOTUPDATED*. I changed UpdateDate to 11/02/2015 (i'm writing on 11/04/2015) & it went to UPDATED... I also tried on other dates like 02/03/2015 and it also went to UPDATED.

What's more, I've readed solutions that don't work...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, `GEQ`, `LSS` etc. comparison operators in `IF` command compare *numbers* or *strings*. Compare next date **strings** yourself:

```
10/04/2016  // the least string although the biggest date 
11/04/2015  
12/04/2014  // the biggest string although the least date
```

So you should express *dates* in a comparable format, e.g  [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date `YYYY-MM-DD` (year-month-day) or alike `YYYYMMDD`. Supposing (in your locale) the `11/04/2015` date string represents *11th April 2015*:

```
set "thisDate=11/04/2015"
rem "thisDate=%DATE%"
set "AnsiDate=%thisDate:~6,4%-%thisDate:~3,2%-%thisDate:~0,2%"
echo thisDate=%thisDate% AnsiDate=%AnsiDate%
```

should display `thisDate=11/04/2015 AnsiDate=2015-04-11`

**Resources** (required reading):

- [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)